# Different type of base 16?

Tags: radix

Base 16 should go from 0 to F, with F being equal to 15 in base 10. But yet, when I use a base 16 converter found on google (https://www.hexator.com/) , it says that F is equal to 46.

Expected results:

```
0 | 0
1 | 1
2 | 2
3 | 3
4 | 4
5 | 5
6 | 6
7 | 7
8 | 8
9 | 9
a | 10
b | 11
c | 12
d | 13
e | 14 
f | 15
```

Am I miss-interpreting something here?

Comment: 46 is `2E` that converter converts binary data encoded in base 16 as text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That encoder is converting the ASCII value of the letter 'F' into the hexadecimal representation of it. The ASCII value of 'F' is 70, which is 46 when converted into hexadecimal. See this [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

That converter is converting text into its hex representation, not Hex strings into decimal numbers.